# Regex in url to find "/...#/ js

Tags: javascript, regex, string, hash, replace

In this is an example string,

```
"http://jony.aaa.com/remove#/dont-remove/dont/"
```

What is the regex for replacing the `/remove#/` string?

I wish to remove the /...#/ part of the string. I've used (//.*?#/ig,""), but that clears everything from after the 'http:' till the '#' character

Comment: "mexican guitar player" - am I missing something?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑI think he's just referring to his avatar.

Comment: Does the replacement always end in an `#`?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough... I wish to remove the /...#/ part of the string.
I've used (/\/.*?#/ig,""), but that clears everything from after the 'http:' till the '#' character.

Comment: You can use :  \w+(?=#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following should work. It finds a /. Then not a / until it finds one #

```
/\/[^\/]+#/

"http://jony.aaa.com/remove#/dont-remove/dont/".replace(/\/[^\/]+#/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var str = "http://jony.aaa.com/remove#/dont-remove/dont/";
var newString= str.replace(/remove#/i, "whatYouWant");
console.log(newString);
```

Comment: the 'remove' isnt a  fixed string! its meant to be the area to remove
http://jony.aaa.com/ooo#/dont-remove/dont/"

Comment: @ShaiKimchi That is something that should have been in the question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Since the replacement is always ending in a `#` character and is between `/` segments, a simple find and replace should be sufficient for you.

```
var str = 'http://jony.aaa.com/remove#/dont-remove/dont/'; 
var new_str = str.replace(/[^\/]+\#/, "foobar");
```

https://regex101.com/r/xF2eH9/1

Comment: Or even `var new_str = str.replace(/[^\/]+#\//, "foobar");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wouldn't that remove the `/` between `remove#` and `dont-remove`? https://regex101.com/r/xF2eH9/2